# How to recover locally deleted files by AWS CLI sync command?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I was using below command in my python program to delete files from local after syncing it with S3 bucket. But it deleted the files without uploading it to s3. How do I recover the deleted files?

```
// Sync with deletion - local file is deleted
$ aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/MyFolder . --delete delete: MySubdirectory\MyFile3.txt
```

Another thought I have here is that, Sync command suppose to sync data between two things, in my case it is between S3 and local. My understanding was this command will upload and delete. But it didn't upload and only deleted the files. How do I recover now?

Comment: That's what backups are for.

Comment: I don't see how this is even related to AWS, the problem is local to your system.

Comment: The delete operation was done by AWS Sync command. That's why it is related to AWS. Can you tell me when AWS sync command deletes the files locally, it deletes it permanently or there is a way to recover it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please help!! I need your expert opinion.

Comment: I would expect it to delete permanently. Unix doesn't have a non-permanent deletion.

Comment: So unless the AWS sync command implements its own Trash folder of some kind, it would have to delete permanently.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! But why sync didn't upload those files to S3 bucket before deleting? That's what AWS S3 Sync is for? right?

Answer (score 0):

Your command tells the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to synchronize the Amazon S3 bucket with your local directory. Any files modified or added since the last sync (if any) will be replicated to the local directory.

The `--delete` option tells the CLI to remove any files in the destination that are not in the source, therefore producing a true 'sync' between the locations.

As to undeleting files, it depends upon your operating system. You might want to refer to things like: [Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)